# Virtualdub Why isnt it saving my edited down video?

Tags: windows-xp, video, editing, virtualdub, xvid

I'm finished editing a video. I hit save as AVI and the result file is my longer unedited video. Its set to direct stream copy. (i am sure i was able to save like this under XP.) If i switch to full processing mode and save with xvid (defaults) it works but it doesnt look as clear as my original. Its a video of a pixel game which is why it is noticeable.

How do i save my edited down video?

Comment: You probably need to do "Export" rather than "Save".  Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with virtualDub 1.9.9 64 bit edition. I made the video black and white, added motion blur, and cut out a portion of video. When I used File > Save As AVI, it properly saved the file wherever I specified to save it (using full processing mode).

When I used direct stream copy, it cuts out the portion that I removed but does not add any of the effects. It sounds like this is what you are trying to accomplish.

I used the little black markers to select the video segment I want to cut and then used ctrl-x to cut out the segment.

Are you using the latest version of [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/)?

Comment: i am using 1.9.9 x86 on my 64bit cpu. For me ISNT cutting out the portions i removed hence the problem.

Comment: i tried 64bit (why its it called veedub!?!) and isnt finding any of my codecs and i cant open a single video (they are all xvid, asf/wmv, flv and one TSCC). I guess i need to use full processing mode.